# How to Dynamically Add Menus to the Administration

Tags: backend, menu

I want to add a sub menu structure in the backend multiple times for a list of (in this case) manufacturers.

When a new manufacturer is added to the system (could be done in XML, as this does not happen so often), a sub menu with the common structure should be added automatically.

**Example Menu Structure**

- Acme

  - Attributes
  - Categories
- FooBar

  - Attributes
  - Categories
- Magento Inc. Hardware

  - Attributes
  - Categories

and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event `adminhtml_block_html_before` can be hooked to manipulate the configuration that the menu depends on:

In the `config.xml` we add:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <my_module>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore</method>
                </my_module>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Now in the observer we would check if we are in the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` and then manipulate the structure in `Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')`.

In order to be able to mange the submenu structure easily, we can use the configuration XML itself to define a template for the sub menus.

In this template we define placeholders `_code_` and `_name_` which will be replaced later.

So to the `adminhtml.xml` we additionally add:

```
<menutemplate>
    <my_module>
        <_code_>
            <title>_name_</title>
            <children>
                <categories>
                    <title>Categories</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/import_mapping/index/manufacturer/_code_</action>
                </categories>
                <attributes>
                    <title>Attributes</title>
                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/import_mapping/index/manufacturer/_code_</action>
                </attributes>
            </children>
        </_code_>
    </my_module>
</menutemplate>
```

Now in the observer we inject a submenu for each manufacturer. Let's say that `Mage::helper('my_module')->getManufacturers()` returns the list of the manufacturers which could also come from the `config.xml`.
We expect that the menu `catalog/my_module` was already created using the `adminhtml.xml`.

```
/**
 * Add menu structure for each manufacturer
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!($observer->getBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu)) {
        return;
    }
    $config = Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')->getAdminhtmlConfig();
    $menu = $config->getNode('menu');
    /* @var $target Varien_Simplexml_Element */
    $target = $menu->catalog->children->my_module>addChild('children');
    $template = $config->getNode('menutemplate/my_module/_code_');
    $templateXml = $template->asXml();

    $manufacturers = Mage::helper('my_module')->getManufacturers();

    foreach($manufacturers as $code=>$data) {
        $child = simplexml_load_string(
            str_replace(
                array('_code_', '_name_'),
                array($code, $data->label),
                $templateXml
            )
        );
        $target->appendChild($child);
    }
}
```

One note: The menu block is cached. So if the menu entries depend on truly dynamic data, the block cache has to be purged each time this dynamic data changes.