# Dynamic elements in the admin menu

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, adminmenu

I need to add some elements in the **admin** menu based on some conditions (custom logic) so I cannot use `adminhtml/menu.xml` for that. (or can I?)

For example, I need to add inside the products main menu the next structure

- Accessories

  - Accessories type 1
  - Accessories type 2.
  - ...
  - Accessories type N.

Numbers 1 to N are dynamic and may come from different extensions that link to the same class.
Is there an event I can hook on? Or some class I can pluginize?

Comment: you want to create ACL rule?

Comment: That will be the next step, but for now I'm not concerned with this. I just need to display multiple elements based on code not just xml configuration.

Comment: Check this solution. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/how-to-dynamically-add-menus-to-the-administration

Comment: Already saw that. That's for magento 1. The admin menu structure changed in Magento 2.

Comment: I had this type of requirement, I looked for core code, Found something related to it. But Too lazy to start So kicked it. Check this Hope it will help you. 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu.php#L77

Damm Sure. You already reached above  !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a nice, clean solution.
The idea is to pluginize `Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder::getResult()`.
I've added this in the `adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder">
    <plugin name="add-dynamic-menu" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Menu\BuilderPlugin" />
</type>
```

Then my plugin looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Model\Menu;


use Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Menu;
use Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\ItemFactory;

class BuilderPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var ItemFactory
     */
    private $menuItemFactory;

    //... other members here

    /**
     * BuilderPlugin constructor.
     * @param ItemFactory $menuItemFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ItemFactory $menuItemFactory,
        //.... other dependencies here
    ) {
        $this->menuItemFactory = $menuItemFactory;
        //....other assignments here
    }


    /**
     * @param Builder $subject
     * @param Menu $menu
     * @return Menu
     */
    public function afterGetResult(Builder $subject, Menu $menu)
    {
        if (my condition here) {
            /** @var Menu\Item $item */
            $parent = 'Magento_Catalog::catalog'; //adding the menu as part of the catalog main menu
            $item = $this->menuItemFactory->create([
                'data' => [
                    'parent_id' => $parent,
                    'id' => '[Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here',
                    'title' => 'Menu title here',
                    'resource' => '[Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here' 
                ]
            ]);
            $menu->add($item, $parent);
            ///add submenu for the menu item added above
            foreach (loop through my dynamic list as $dynamicItem) {
                $item = $this->menuItemFactory->create([
                    'data' => [
                        'parent_id' => '[Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here', //id of menu above
                        'id' => '[Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here_'.$dynamicItem->getCode(), //give it a unique id
                        'title' => $dynamicItem->getTitle(), //title of the submenu
                        'resource' => '[Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here', //same ACL key as above, or it can be different
                        'action' => $dynamicItem->getUrl() //url for the main menu
                    ]
                ]);
                $menu->add($item, [Vendor]_[Module]::some_key_here'); //add is as a child for the menu item above
            }

        }
        return $menu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution for Magento 1 mentioned by @avesh in the comments above also applies to Magento 2. You can still listen to event `adminhtml_block_html_before`. The sample code below adds a "Test Menu" under "Catalog".

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_block_html_before">
        <observer name="Vendor_Module_Custom_Menu" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore" />
    </event>    
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore.php:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AdminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore implements ObserverInterface
{        
    protected $menuItemFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Item\Factory $menuItemFactory
    ) {
        $this->menuItemFactory = $menuItemFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();

        if($block instanceof \Magento\Backend\Block\Menu){
            $menuModel = $block->getMenuModel();

            $itemData = array(
                'id'          => 'testMenuId',
                'title'       => 'Test Menu',
                'resource'    => 'Magento_Catalog::products',               
                'action'      => 'module/action/'
            );

            $item = $this->menuItemFactory->create($itemData);
            $menuModel->add($item, 'Magento_Catalog::inventory', 100); //$menuModel->add($item, $parentId, $index)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it should work. +1 from me, but what I don't like is the fact that it hooks into a general method, called for a lot of classes. But indeed it can be used as a last resort. It's pretty clean.

Comment: Thanks @Marius, I learnt a lot from your posts. You're like the god of Magento.

Answer (score -3):

Check this one
https://gist.github.com/herveguetin/7c78e3991687744f164b

Convert this line to M2

```
$menu = Mage::getSingleton('admin/config')->getAdminhtmlConfig()->getNode('menu/MAIN_MENU_ITEM/children/MENU_ITEMS_CONTAINER/children');
```

Comment: This won't work. The config files in magento 2 are not merge into one huge config. They are separated by role.